# Changing coordinate system causes clockwise rotations

Tags: c++, matrix, glm-math

### The task

I need to convert the coordinate system to +X forward, +Y right and +Z up (left-handed, like the one in Unreal Engine). The crucial part is that I want my camera to face its forward axis (again, like in Unreal Engine). Here is how it works in Unreal:
[image: world]
[image: local]

### The problem

I have managed to achieve both things: my camera now faces its forward direction and world coordinates are the same as in UE, HOWEVER, I've stumbled upon a big issue. For each object:

- pitch rotation (around RightVector) is now clockwise
- yaw rotation (around UpVector) is now clockwise
- roll rotation (around ForwardVector) is counter-clockwise (as it was before)

I need these rotations to be all counter-clockwise (as per standard) and keep the camera facing the forward vector.

### My current solution attempt

My current setup relies on rotating the projection and camera view matrices (model matrix in my code is called entity matrix):

```
#define GLM_FORCE_LEFT_HANDED // it's defined somewhere else but so you're aware
// Transform::VectorForward = (1, 0, 0) // these are used below
// Transform::VectorRight =   (0, 1, 0)
// Transform::VectorUp =      (0, 0, 1)

// The entity matrix update function which updates the model matrix for each object
virtual void UpdateEntityMatrix()
{
    auto m = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.f), m_Transform.Location);
    m = glm::rotate(m, glm::radians(m_Transform.Rotation[2]), Transform::VectorUp); // yaw rotation
    m = glm::rotate(m, glm::radians(m_Transform.Rotation[1]), Transform::VectorRight); // pitch rotation
    m = glm::rotate(m, glm::radians(m_Transform.Rotation[0]), Transform::VectorForward); // roll rotation
    m_EntityMatrix = glm::scale(m, m_Transform.Scale);
}

// The entity matrix update in my camera class (child of entity) which also updates the view matrix
void Camera::UpdateEntityMatrix()
{
    SceneEntity::UpdateEntityMatrix();

    auto m = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.f), m_Transform.Location);
    m = glm::rotate(m, glm::radians(180.f), GetRightVector()); // NOTE: I'm getting the current Forward/Right/Up vectors of the entity
    m = glm::rotate(m, glm::radians(m_Transform.Rotation[2]), GetUpVector()); // yaw rotation
    m = glm::rotate(m, glm::radians(m_Transform.Rotation[1]), GetRightVector()); // pitch rotation
    m = glm::rotate(m, glm::radians(m_Transform.Rotation[0]), GetForwardVector()); // roll rotation
    m = glm::scale(m, m_Transform.Scale);

    m_ViewMatrix = glm::inverse(m);
    m_ViewProjectionMatrix = m_ProjectionMatrix * m_ViewMatrix;
}

void PerspectiveCamera::UpdateProjectionMatrix()
{
    m_ProjectionMatrix = glm::perspective(glm::radians(m_FOV), m_Width / m_Height, m_NearClip, m_FarClip);
    // we want the camera to face +x:
    m_ProjectionMatrix = glm::rotate(m_ProjectionMatrix, glm::radians(-90.f), Transform::VectorUp);
    m_ProjectionMatrix = glm::rotate(m_ProjectionMatrix, glm::radians(90.f), Transform::VectorRight);
}
```

This is my result so far (the camera visualization thing shows the rotation of currently used camera):
[image: current]

### What else I tried

I tried modifying the model matrix (note the `-`):

```
virtual void UpdateEntityMatrix()
    {
        auto m = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.f), m_Transform.Location);
        m = glm::rotate(m, glm::radians(-m_Transform.Rotation[2]), Transform::VectorUp); // yaw rotation
        m = glm::rotate(m, glm::radians(-m_Transform.Rotation[1]), Transform::VectorRight); // pitch rotation
        m = glm::rotate(m, glm::radians(m_Transform.Rotation[0]), Transform::VectorForward); // roll rotation
        m_EntityMatrix = glm::scale(m, m_Transform.Scale);
    }
```

But it makes my camera not face forward anymore (the view is the camera's rotation but mirrored on the Y and Z axis):
[image: attempt1]

Itried to fix it by applying the same change when calculating the camera view matrix but it didn't help (still mirrored or some other issues).

On top of that, I tried experimenting with the `glm::lookAt` functions to create the view matrix but never achieved anything.

### Update: I've found a solution

I think my problem was actually defining a counter-clockwise rotation. It turns out Unreal's rotations are not consistently counter-clockwise. I think it's best to define a counter-clockwise rotation when looking in the direction pointed by the direction arrow - as if you were behind it. Here is my conclusion:
[image: Mine]
[image: Unreal]

### Conclusion

Unless somebody finds an errorin the system I defined, I'll stick to it. The code is contained in the **My current solution attempt** section. It seems I was correct from the get-go.

However, the answer provided by @paddy does solve my original issue - converting clockwise to counter-clockwise. Upon further attempts, I was able to correctly replicate Unreal's system while keeping my camera facing forward.

Comment: When you need to perform operations in a different coordinate system, the usual approach is to create a transformation matrix that converts from one to the other. And of course the inverse of that matrix goes back the other way. So if you have some operation `U` to perform in "Unreal" space, and you have `T` that maps from your own space into Unreal space, then you would do something like: `T * U * T'`.

Comment: That's helpful, I didn't know that. Although, I'm not sure how to apply this concept to my current problem. I've been trying to use `T = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.f), glm::vec3(1.f, 1.f, -1.f))` to mirror the view matrix after the changes described in **What else I tried** but I wasn't successful. Is that the right idea?

Comment: @paddy Please convert your comment to an answer. I'll edit my question to contain the exact answer, but your idea was the key here.